# How to clean flux from a DDR footprint without ESD risk?

Tags: esd

I could be paranoid, but I have to replace a batch of DDRs from a board. Those are connected directly to the IC, they aren't GPIOs, so I believe the ESD risk is higher.

I need to remove the old solder left behind from the old DDRs and to do so I will use solder wick and no-clean flux. I will then clean the flux using isopropyl alcohol and a brush.

How do I minimise ESD risk in the process?

I will be using an ESD wristband, on an ESD-safe surface, but I'm worried about static charge in the brush.

Am I overthinking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ESD-safe brush, which has conductive handle and/or bristles. Many are available from all of the usual places, for example - this one plucked at random from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/desco/35692/16-1348-ND/966356) :

[image: ESD brush]

[More options listed here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/static-control-esd-clean-room-products/clean-room-swabs-and-brushes/611?k=&pkeyword=&pv183=6595&pv183=6596&pv5=14553&pv5=14555&pv5=9333&pv5=9327&pv5=9339&FV=ffe00263&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) some conductive/dissipative, some dissipative/conductive etc.